# Xpath expression to get value from CDATA

Tags: xml, xpath, apache-camel

I am trying to get the value for applicationId from the following request through xpath :-

```
<ApplicationStatusNotificationRequestMessage xmlns="http://schemas.co.za/application">
    <b>http://localhost/test/sonoras</b>
    <c>POST</c>
    <Data><![CDATA[{"applicationId":"12345678","status":"ACTIVATED"}]]></Data>
</ApplicationStatusNotificationRequestMessage>
```

The xpath expression I am using:

```
//app:ApplicationStatusNotificationRequestMessage/app:Data[@applicationId]/text()
```

Unfortunately, the XPath is not returning any value.

Comment: You have an error: <c>POST</Method>

Answer (score 2):

The JSON content inside your `<d>` element is just a `text()` node. The "applicationId" in your JSON string will not be evaluated as an attribute. The fact that CDATA was used is irrelevant.

Your predicate is attempting to select the `text()` from `app:Data` elements that have an `@applicationId`, and there are none.

Use the [`contains()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-contains) function to restrict to elements that have that JSON property in the `text()`

```
//app:ApplicationStatusNotificationRequestMessage/
  app:Data[contains(., 'applicationId')]/text()
```

If you want to obtain the applicationId value, you will need to parse the JSON string. There are a number of ways to do that. Depending upon which version of XPath you are using, you will have more/less options. A few examples of how you might obtain the value:

**XPath 3.0** - using [json-to-xml()](https://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/#json-to-xml):

```
json-to-xml(//app:ApplicationStatusNotificationRequestMessage/
        app:Data[contains(., 'applicationId')]/text())/*/*[@key='applicationId']/text()
```

**XPath 2.0** - using [replace()](https://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/#replace):

```
replace(//app:ApplicationStatusNotificationRequestMessage/
        app:Data[contains(., 'applicationId')]/text(), '.*applicationId.*?:.(\d+).,.*', '$1')
```

**XPath 1.0** - using [substring-before()](https://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/#substring-before) and [substring-after()](https://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/#substring-after):

```
substring-before(
  substring-after(//app:ApplicationStatusNotificationRequestMessage/
                    app:Data[contains(., 'applicationId')]/text(), 
         'applicationId&quot;:&quot;'), 
  '&quot;,')
```

Comment: Hi. I implemented the contains function as you suggested, but I am still getting the following output: {"applicationId":"12345678","status":"ACTIVATED"}

Comment: Yes, that selected the text in the Data element. If you want only the numeric value of the applicationId, you will need to parse it out. What version of XPath are you using?

Answer (score 0):

If you can't register a namespace you can go with this:

```
"/*[name()='ApplicationStatusNotificationRequestMessage']/*[name()='Data']"
```

Comment: Hi. I am able to add a namespace, but I am not able to get the value of applicationId